# What is the proper term for a ternary digit?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, mathematics, computing

A binary digit is a **bit**.

Is there an equivalent term for a *three-state digit?*

(e.g., a digit representing true, false, or unknown)

Comment: I'm not sure exactly why this was migrated, but so far as I'm concerned what we're talking about here is normally referred to as a [Tri-state variable](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/c-prog/conversations/topics/73904)

Comment: ... but on the gripping hand...

Comment: @FumbleFingers, tri-state logic is entirely different. Trinary logic has 3 active states representing 3 different values. Tri-state logic has two active states and a passive state indicating two values and "let somebody else decide the value".

Comment: @The Photon/l I bet you know exactly how many angels can dance on the head of a pin, too! :) Seriously - I never mentioned *tri-state **logic*** (a slightly odd name, since it seems to be more about the physics of digital circuitry, rather than *logic* as such).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Trit.

At least, according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system):

> Analogous to a bit, a ternary digit is a **trit** (trinary digit)

Comment: I don't think this is the correct answer to OP's question. Not every three-state variable is a trit. A trit is a ternary *digit*, which means it is a component of a radix-3 numeral. There are several ways to represent numbers with three-state quantities (‘balanced ternary’ for example), and the components of those representations might be called trits. (continued)

Comment: But OP asked specifically about variables that represent true, false and *unknown*, and there is no way to compose such quantities into numerals. It is a little hard to say for sure, because ‘trit’ is not a common term, but I think ordinary usage of ‘trit’ does not extend to such situations, and I would be reluctant to believe that it did without seeing specific examples.

Comment: @Mark - OP gave an **example** of true, false and unknown. Which can be represented by a trit.

Comment: @MarkDominus: It is just as easy to say you cannot represent true and false with numerals, and yet if you did a great many programming languages would loudly disagree. A significant subset of them treat `0` and `1` as binary values, and C has no other way of representing. You can trivially represent t/f/u.

Comment: @MarkDominus OP's question is explicitly about the term for a "ternary digit." What's the conflict here?

Answer (score 8):

I think that the question contains a faulty premise.  There are many types of [three-valued logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic).  Some three-valued systems include:

- A [ternary numeral system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system), in which each digit is called a "trit" (short for TRinary digIT).  Each trit can be 0, 1, or 2.  The least-significant trit represents zero, one, or two; the second-least-significant trit represents three, six, or nine; and so on.
- A [tri-state system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic), in which an electronic signal can have a high, low, or unasserted state.
- A [nullable boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type), in which a variable can be true, false, or unknown/null.  A sequence of nullable booleans doesn't represent any larger number; it works like a nullable bitfield.

I would therefore say that a *"digit" representing true, false, unknown* is not a digit at all, but rather a **nullable boolean**, or possibly a **tri-state value**.

Comment: Along the lines of a "nullable boolean", some languages like OCaml or [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx) would call them an `Option<bool>` which means it can have the values of `None`, `Some(true)` or 'Some(false)`.

Comment: The Haskell language calls that the Maybe monad.  A type of `Maybe Boolean` would be one of three values: `Just True`, `Just False`, or `Nothing`.  

And while that is one of the tri-state booleans, it isn't the only one.  Instead of "unknown" the third option could be almost any useful value: "maybe", "partially true/false", "n/a", etc.  Depends on what you want to model with such a system.

Answer (score 4):

**Trit** for trinary digit.
According to <s>[Princeton](https://www.princeton.edu/~achaney/tmve/wiki100k/docs/Ternary_numeral_system.html)</s> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_numeral_system), since the Princeton article was retrieved from Wikipedia:

> Analogous to a bit, a ternary digit is a **trit** (**tr**inary dig**it**). One trit contains log<sub>2</sub>3 (about 1.58496) bits of information.

Trits and base 3 computing and hardware have been researched and developed in the 50's. The idea was to eliminate the 2 stage binary comparison by implementing the ternary logic *less*, *equal*, or *greater* outcomes or *true*, *false*, or *unknown*.

I was not able to find any published work with the definition of a *trit*, but a few articles talking about it and its implementation.
This is the closest to a definition given in [American Scientist](http://www.americanscientist.org/issues/pub/third-base/3) in an article about the third base:

> Setun operated on numbers composed of 18 ternary digits, or *trits*, ...

Comment: And a **nat** is a unit of information in base *e*. Indeed, another reason that there was research into ternary logic in the '50s was that a trit is closer to a nat than a bit is.

Comment: Note that the link that you have posted contains an extract of the Wikipedia article that linked at the bottom. So, the source of the material is Wikipedia and not _Princeton_

Comment: @Aditya, it's interesting that Princeton has taken that article from Wikipedia, which is not a reliable source since anybody can say anything there. Now I understand why that page says "Do not cite". Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @slybloty: Do you consider SE to be a "reliable source"? It's virtually the case that "anybody can say anything" here (for a while). Both platforms rely on communal editing to weed out unreliable information in the long run.